# Error loading resource library. (0x8007007E) when printing

Tags: printing, resources

I added the kB954607 GDI security hotfix to our development cluster the other day and now we're having printing problems (again...sigh).

Error loading resource library. (0x8007007E)

I've tried deregistering the RSClientPrint.dll and then printing to have it install again, but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed!

I did everything suggested on this forum, and still a persistent problem on only some of the machines. The ultimate fix was to delete all of the RSClientPrint*.* files (13 rll files, 1 inf and 1 dll) from the Windows\System32 folder. I don't think they're supposed to be there, and don't know how they got there, because they weren't on any of the machines with no printing problems. In any event, it fixed the problem on 23 computers with printing issues.